# How to write unit test for LogoutEventStream trigger

Tags: unit-test

So we use after insert trigger on "LogoutEventStream" for some actions on logout.

My question is about, how to write tests for this? How do we call the insert record on LogoutEventStream?

Here's the link to the actual trigger
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_logouteventstream.htm

Comment: I'd suggest cross posting this to the [Salesforce Identity group in the Trailblazer Community](https://success.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F9300000001q1NCAQ)

Comment: Have you tried creating a community user and then navigate to `Network.getLogoutUrl(networkId)`?

Answer (score 2):

here is the solution for unitTest:

```java
 Test.startTest();    
 EventBus.publish(new LogoutEventStream());
 Test.stopTest();
```

Hope this helps others with same issue

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your test class  :

```java
   @isTest
   public static void scenario1(){
       User u = new User();
       u.Email = 'test@tste.com';
       u.Username = 'test@tstetstete.com';
       u.MobilePhone = '1234567890';
       u.CommunityNickname = 'testssf';
       Profile p = [SELECT Id,Name FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'System Administrator'];
       p.PermissionsCustomizeApplication  = True;
       u.ProfileId = p.id;
       u.LastName = 'test';
       u.Alias = 'tstsfsf';
       u.TimeZoneSidKey = 'Asia/Kolkata';
       u.LocaleSidKey = 'en_US';
       u.LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US';
       u.EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8';
       u.IsActive = True;
       insert u;
       
       Test.startTest();
       User u1 = [SELECT Id, IsTeamMemberActive__c, UserName FROM User WHERE Id =:u.id];
       LogoutEventStream event = new LogoutEventStream();
       event.UserName = u1.UserName;
       EventBus.publish(event);
       Test.stopTest(); 
   }
```